# how to fill qvector which is member of MainWindow by means of qtablewidget from Qdialog

Tags: c++, qt

I created `MainWindow` class by using QT Creator. Then I added some `pushbutton` to `MainWindow` to open a new dialog which I created form class by using QT Form Designer.

When a user clicks on the button a new dialog opens. The new dialog has a `QTableWidget` and a `pushbutton`. The user can fill `QTableWidget` with some values and after clicked the dialog's `pushbutton` I would like to send these values to `MainWindow` to fill `QVector x` and `QVector y` which are attributes of `MainWindow` class.

How can I achieve that?
How can I get an instance of `MainWindow` from `QDialog`? What would I write inside the function:

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    // Code Here
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance,

Peter
below the code of my two classes

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "dialog.h"
#include <QVector>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow() override;

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog *geometria;
    QVector<double> x;
    QVector<double> y;

private slots:
 void generate();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H 
////////////////////////////////////////

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
geometria=new Dialog(this);
   connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(generuj_przekroj()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

    delete ui;

}

 void MainWindow::generate()
 {

     geometria->show();

 }

////////////////////////////////////

#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog();
 public slots:
    void wcisnij();
    void  wstaw_wiersz();
    bool  eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event);

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;


};

#endif // DIALOG_H

/////////////////////////////////////////

#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include "xy.h"

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(10);
        ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(2);
        ui->tableWidget->setCurrentCell(4,1);
        ui->tableWidget->installEventFilter(this);

    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(wcisnij()));
    connect(ui->tableWidget,SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()),this,SLOT(wcisnij()));
    connect(ui->tableWidget,SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()),this,SLOT(wstaw_wiersz()));
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::wcisnij()
{

   int r=ui->tableWidget->currentRow();
   int c=ui->tableWidget->currentColumn();
}

void  Dialog::wstaw_wiersz()
{
    int n=0;
    n=ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
    if(ui->tableWidget->currentRow()==n-1)
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(n+1);
}

bool  Dialog::eventFilter(QObject *target, QEvent *event) {

if (target==ui->tableWidget && event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {

      QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
      if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Return|| keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Down )
      {
                  int n=0;
                  int k=0;
                  n=ui->tableWidget->currentRow();
                  k=ui->tableWidget->currentColumn();
                  ui->tableWidget->setCurrentCell(n+1,k);

      }

      if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Up )
      {
                  int n=0;
                  int k=0;
                  n=ui->tableWidget->currentRow();
                  k=ui->tableWidget->currentColumn();
                  ui->tableWidget->setCurrentCell(n-1,k);

      }

    return true;

}

else
     return QObject::eventFilter(target, event);

}


void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you Marcel.Now it looks much better.

Comment: Have you got any ideas?

Comment: Sorry.  My eyes are foggy.  1AM.  Im assuming you are using a QTableWidget.  Do you know how to get the data out of it?

Comment: Yes I know but dont know how to pass it to mainWindow.

Comment: please go to sleep.We will return to this on day:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is to load the data in your Dialog, and then emit a signal to MainWindow that it is ready, and let MainWindow get the data.
Add to Dialog.h:

```
public:
    std::vector<float> getX() { return x; }
    std::vector<float> getY() { return y; }

signals:
    dataReady();

private:
    QVector<double> x;
    QVector<double> y;
```

Add to Dialog.cpp:

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
    for (int r=0; r<rows; ++r)
        for (int c=0; c<rows; ++c) {
            QTableWidgetItem cell = tableWidget->item(r, c);
            QString contents = cell.text();
            double val = contents.toDouble();
            x.push_back(val);
        }

    //  And do the same to collect y data

    emit dataReady();
```

Add to MainWindow.h

```
private slots:
    void onDataReady();
```

Add to MainWindow.cpp

```
    MainWindow::MainWindow(...etc
{ ...
    geometria=new Dialog(this);

    connect(*geometria, SIGNAL(dataReady()), this, SLOT(onDataReady()));
    ...
}

        MainWindow::onDataReady()
{
    x = geometria->getX();
    y = geometria->getY();
}
```

Comment: wow thank you for your reply.After work I will check if it works

Comment: @Piotr Cool!  If you're satisfied with an answer then go ahead and mark the question as answered by clicking the little checkmark  to the left of the answer.  That lets folks know you have your answer and it helps out the person who answered you a little by increasing their reputation.